# how to redirect stderr with: android adb exec-out run-as cat foo.log 2>foo.error > foo.log

Tags: android, adb, stderr

i am using the script below on unrooted 2013 nexus 7's with android 6.0.1 and may patches. if the log files exists, all is well. if not, stderr goes to the local foo.log file on my pc.

is there a way to fix this?

tried a shell here doc, but that does not seem to work with exec-out.

```
    set package=com.tayek.tablet.gui.android.cb7
    ::setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    for %%i in (0a9196e8) do (
        adb devices -l | grep %%i >nul
        if errorlevel 1 (
            echo %%i is not connected!
        ) else (
            echo %%i is connected.
            adb -s %%i shell run-as %package% ls -l /data/data/%package%/files
            adb -s %%i exec-out run-as %package% cat /data/data/%package%/files/tablet.0.0.log 2>%%i.0.0.errors.txt 1> %%i.0.0.log
            adb -s %%i exec-out run-as %package% cat /data/data/%package%/files/tablet.1.0.log 2>%%i.1.0.errors.txt 1> %%i.1.0.log
)
)
```